# Image seclection not working properly in Add / Remove Fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created Add / Remove fields to collect data such as Member Pic, Member name, Member Email, Member Role, and Member FB Id. Everything is working perfectly.

The only problem I am facing is that when I want to change the already saved image of a member with a new one, then it changes the first image only. Means If I try to change the second or third or next member's image it updates the first image only. This happens only with the pre-saved images only.

If I add a new member then it works perfectly.

Following is the code:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header text-center">
    <b>Team Members</b>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">

<?php

$member_details = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT member_details FROM {$wpdb->prefix}project_members WHERE author_id = %s AND project_id = %s", $current_user_id, $project_id ) );

$member_details_decode = json_decode( $member_details, true );

?>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">

<?php

if ( ! empty( $member_details_decode['member_images'][0] ) ) { ?>

  <img src="<?php echo site_url( '/wp-content/img/member-images/' ); echo $member_details_decode['member_images'][0]; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" id="output_member0">

<?php } else { ?>

  <img src="<?php echo site_url( '/wp-content/assets/img/blank-image.png' ); ?>" class="img-thumbnail" id="output_member0">

<?php }

?>

<br><br>

<label class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-file">Select Image<input type="file" name="member_image[]" onchange="preview_member(event, 0)" style="display: none;"></label>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="member_name"><b>Member Name</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_name[]" value="<?php if ( $member_details_decode['member_names'][0] != '' ) echo esc_attr( $member_details_decode['member_names'][0] ); ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="member_email"><b>Email Address</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_email[]" value="<?php if ( $member_details_decode['member_emails'][0] != '' ) echo esc_attr( $member_details_decode['member_emails'][0] ); ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="member_role"><b>Role in Project</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_role[]" value="<?php if ( $member_details_decode['member_roles'][0] != '' ) echo esc_attr( $member_details_decode['member_roles'][0] ); ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="member_fb"><b>Facebook Username</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_fb[]" value="<?php if ( $member_details_decode['member_fbs'][0] != '' ) echo esc_attr( $member_details_decode['member_fbs'][0] ); ?>">
  </div>

    </div>

  </div>

<?php

$member_count = count( $member_details_decode['member_images'] );

for ( $i=1; $i < $member_count; $i++ ) { ?>

<div class="all-member-fields"><hr>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">

<?php

if ( ! empty( $member_details_decode['member_images'][$i] ) ) { ?>

  <img src="<?php echo site_url( '/wp-content/img/member-images/' ); echo $member_details_decode['member_images'][$i]; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" id="output_member0">

<?php } else { ?>

  <img src="<?php echo site_url( '/wp-content/assets/img/blank-image.png' ); ?>" class="img-thumbnail" id="output_member0">

<?php }

?>

<br><br>

<label class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-file">Select Image<input type="file" name="member_image[]" onchange="preview_member(event, 0)" style="display: none;"></label>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="member_name"><b>Member Name</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_name[]" value="<?php if ( $member_details_decode['member_names'][$i] != '' ) echo esc_attr( $member_details_decode['member_names'][$i] ); ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="member_email"><b>Email Address</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_email[]" value="<?php if ( $member_details_decode['member_emails'][$i] != '' ) echo esc_attr( $member_details_decode['member_emails'][$i] ); ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="member_role"><b>Role in Project</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_role[]" value="<?php if ( $member_details_decode['member_roles'][$i] != '' ) echo esc_attr( $member_details_decode['member_roles'][$i] ); ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="member_fb"><b>Facebook Username</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_fb[]" value="<?php if ( $member_details_decode['member_fbs'][$i] != '' ) echo esc_attr( $member_details_decode['member_fbs'][$i] ); ?>">
  </div>

    </div>

  </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-member-fields" style="float: right;">Remove Member</button><br><br></div>

<?php }

?>

  <div id="member-fields">

  </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="add-member-fields">Add Member</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var i = 0;

function preview_member(event, inp) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  console.log(inp);
  reader.onload = function() {
    var output = document.getElementById('output_member' + inp);
    output.src = reader.result;
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //fadeout selected item and remove
  $(document).on("click", '#remove-member-fields', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(this).empty();
        return false;
      });
  });

  //add input
  $('#add-member-fields').click(function() {
    i++;

    var rows = `<div class="all-member-fields"><hr><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( site_url('/wp-content/assets/img/blank-image.png') ); ?>" class="img-thumbnail" id="output_member${i}"><br><br><label class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-file">Select Image<input type="file" name="member_image[]" onchange="preview_member(event, ${i})" style="display: none;"></label></div><div class="col-md-8"><div class="form-group"><label for="member_name"><b>Member Name</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_name[]"></div><div class="form-group"><label for="member_email"><b>Email Address</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_email[]"></div><div class="form-group"><label for="member_role"><b>Role in Project</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_role[]"></div><div class="form-group"><label for="member_fb"><b>Facebook Username</b> <b style="color:#FF0000;">*</b></label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="member_fb[]"></div></div></div><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-member-fields" style="float: right;">Remove Member</button><br><br></div>`;

    $(rows)
      .fadeIn("slow")
      .appendTo('#member-fields');
    return false;
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Provide us with actual $member_details array/object, so that we can see a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add your `$i` to `preview_member()` and to image `id` in your loop

Your `preview_member()` functions changes element with id `output_member0` everytime.

In your `for` loop:

Change images ID from `id="output_member0"` to `id="output_member<?= $i ?>"` in your

Change `onchange="preview_member(event, 0)"` to `onchange="preview_member(event, <?= $i ?>)"`

Comment: Hello @Kloshar4o, This problem is solved but another got raised. Now when I add a new field and try to upload photo then it updates the second image which is already saved. In short the new field is not updating its own field.